# Connection with salesforce is slow from Talend

Tags: salesforce, talend, dataloader

I am using the tSalesforceOutputBulkExec component in Talend to push records to salesforce. It is taking too much time to send 10 records to salesforce (more than 50 seconds).
I tried the same thing with the data loader but couldn't see any issue there.

I am also getting below warnings:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.talend.components.api.component.runtime.JarRuntimeInfo (file:XXX/configuration/.m2/repository/org/talend/components/components-api/0.28.2/components-api-0.28.2.jar) to field java.net.URL.factory
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.talend.components.api.component.runtime.JarRuntimeInfo
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a bulk job in Salesforce is some overhead, for small amounts of data a simple load is faster.
The warnings are from the Java Virtual Mashine. The code Talend uses contains illegal method calls. This calls do currently work, but a future Java version might stop this calls. Talend should know about the warnings, you can ignore them.